# ImportError: libprotobuf.so.29: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python

try run this https://github.com/microsoft/Relation-Aware-Global-Attention-Networks and find problems

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main_imgreid.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorboardX import SummaryWriter
  File "/home/zhaoxin/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorboardX/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .torchvis import TorchVis
  File "/home/zhaoxin/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorboardX/torchvis.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .writer import SummaryWriter
  File "/home/zhaoxin/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorboardX/writer.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .comet_utils import CometLogger
  File "/home/zhaoxin/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorboardX/comet_utils.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .summary import _clean_tag
  File "/home/zhaoxin/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorboardX/summary.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .proto.summary_pb2 import Summary
  File "/home/zhaoxin/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorboardX/proto/summary_pb2.py", line 7, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
  File "/home/zhaoxin/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/protobuf/descriptor.py", line 47, in <module>
    from google.protobuf.pyext import _message
```

Comment: Please provide additional details on what your OS is, how you installed Python (presumably Anaconda?) and the packages in question.